# Как программно прокрутить скролл определённого элемента?

Tags: javascript, angular, прокрутка

Я хочу проекте angular прокрутить скролл в определённом элементе.
Как это сделать средствами ангуляра либо просто на js ?
window.scrollTo не подходит, так как это один из вложенных элементов.

Comment: Добавьте код, сейчас не понятно, что это за вложенный элемент, как вы пытаетесь до него проскролить и т.д.

Comment: через `@ViewChild` или `@ViewChildren` получите вложенный элемент ElementRef<> и примените для него scrollTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так примените `scrollTo` для вашего элемента, а не для `window`.

```js
document.querySelector('div.container').scrollTo({top: 1600,behavior: "smooth"});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути
    меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути
    меня
    <br> Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>Крути меня<br>
  </div>
</div>
```